# Can SCP-096 track down and kill anyone who has seen its face?

Tags: scp-foundation

In the "file" of [SCP-096](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-096), it states that after a person views its face (this person becoming SCP-096-1) "no known material or method can impede SCP-096's progress".

Does this mean this SCP can track down and kill anyone who has seen its face no matter the distance or material in between the two?

Comment: To clarify, I am asking if it can destroy any material in this state.

Answer (score 4):

If you [look at the next line in the SCP wiki](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-096) it states:

> Documented speeds have varied from thirty-five (35) km/h to ███ km/h, and seems to depend on distance from SCP-096-1. At this point, no known material or method can impede SCP-096's progress. ***The actual position of SCP-096-1 does not seem to affect SCP-096's response; it seems to have an innate sense of SCP-096-1's location. Note: This reaction does not occur when viewing artistic depictions (see Document 096-1)*** .
>
> Upon arriving at SCP-096-1's location, SCP-096 will proceed to kill and [DATA EXPUNGED] SCP-096-1. 100% of cases have left no traces of SCP-096-1. SCP-096 will then sit down for several minutes before regaining its composure and becoming docile once again. It will then attempt to make its way back to its natural habitat, [DATA REDACTED]

(Emphasis mine)

So by saying that actual position doesn't matter and an "innate sense" it suggests that yes, it can do this regardless of distance/material.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the article saying "no known material or method can impede SCP-096’s progress" should already give the answer: Yeah, SCP-096 can chase down and kill everything [except SCP-682.](http://www.scpwiki.com/experiment-log-t-98816-oc108-682)

Comment: "except 682" ...and [Moon Champion](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/the-bowe-decommission-part-three), and [173](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/consequences-and-collarbones).